# Collect column range value combined in one cell followed by comma and end with & seperator

Tags: excel, vba6

I am trying to get the collect combined value in one cell followed by comma and end with &
Column range : AM4:AM20 may be with value or blank.
I need to collect this value combined together with comma and with & seperator

AM4 = ABCD1

AM5 = ABCD2

AM6 = ABCD3

AM7 = ABCD4

AM8 = ""
AM9 =""

eg., **BB4 = ABCD1, ABCD2, ABCD3 & ABCD4**

I tried this code

```
Sub GetPipeData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim collectedValues As String
    Dim addComma As Boolean

    ' Set the worksheet containing the values
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT") 

    ' Find the last used row in column AM
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AM").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Initialize the collectedValues variable
    collectedValues = ""
    addComma = False ' Initialize the flag to not add a comma

    ' Loop through the cells in column AM from row 4 to the last used row
    For Each cell In ws.Range("AM4:AM20" & lastRow)
        ' Check if the cell is not empty
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            ' If addComma is True, add a comma before the value
            If addComma Then
                collectedValues = collectedValues & ", "
            End If
            ' Add the value to the collectedValues variable
            collectedValues = collectedValues & cell.Value
            ' Set addComma to True for the next iteration
            addComma = True
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Print the collected values in cell BB4
    ws.Range("BB4").Value = collectedValues
End Sub
```

Expected result

**BB4 = ABCD1, ABCD2, ABCD3 & ABCD
**
Please help me to achieve this task. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could just use a worksheet formula:

```
=LET(
    Φ,AM4:AM20,
    SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",,Φ),", "," & ",MAX(1,SUM(N(Φ<>""))-1))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the added Do...Loop you can get the required result.

```vb
Sub GetPipeData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim collectedValues As String
    Dim addComma As Boolean

    ' Set the worksheet containing the values
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT")

    ' Find the last used row in column AM
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AM").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Initialize the collectedValues variable
    collectedValues = ""
    'addComma = False ' Initialize the flag to not add a comma

    ' Loop through the cells in column AM from row 4 to the last used row
    For Each cell In ws.Range("AM4:AM20")
        ' Check if the cell is not empty
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.value) Then
            ' If addComma is True, add a comma before the value
            If addComma Then
                collectedValues = collectedValues & ", "
            End If
            ' Add the value to the collectedValues variable
            collectedValues = collectedValues & cell.value
            ' Set addComma to True for the next iteration
            addComma = True
        End If
    Next cell
    'This code added
    pos = 1
    Do While InStr(pos + 1, collectedValues, ",") <> 0
        pos = InStr(pos + 1, collectedValues, ",")
    Loop
    If pos<>1 Then collectedValues = Left(collectedValues, pos - 1) & " &" & Mid(collectedValues, pos + 1)
    'Till here
    ' Print the collected values in cell BB4
    ws.Range("BB4").value = collectedValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, got 2 solutions for 1 query. happy. I've learnt.